# Ratio of continuous probabilities

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable in $\mathbb R$. I have two continuous functions, $g(X)$ and $h(X)$. I would like to show that

$$
\frac{Pr(g(X)=g(x))}{Pr(h(X)=h(x))} = \frac{p_{g(X)}(x)}{p_{h(X)}(x)}
$$
where $p_{g(X)}$ and $p_{h(X)}$ are the probability density functions of the random variables $Y = g(X)$ and $Z = h(X)$ respectively.

1. Does this formulation even make sense? It feels like 0 / 0. But, since the Riemann slice width seems to "cancel out", it seems plausible that this would work.
2. Is the conclusion correct? How could I prove it rigorously, or find a counterexample? I'm willing to apply all kinds of nice conditions on $g$, $h$, and $X$.

Comment: I don't know how it works out, but a natural way to start towards a formalism is to consider a ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ and consider the limit of the ratio of the probabilities $Y$ and $Z$ lie in these regions respectively as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: I like that approach; is it kosher, though, to assume that it's the same $\epsilon$ for both top and bottom? Maybe I'm overthinking it, and the "rate" at which $\epsilon$ goes to 0 doesn't matter so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reformulate the statement in terms of Radon-Nikodym derivatives. Let $P_g$ be the measure $P_g(A) = P_X(g^{-1}(A))$, where $P_X$ is the probability distribution of $X$. Define $P_h$ similarly. If $P_g$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $P_h$ then the RN derivative $\frac{dP_g}{dP_h}$ exists and satisfies $$p_{g(X)} = p_{h(X)}\frac{dP_g}{dP_h}$$ The absolute continuity requirement is concretely phrased as : if the probability of $h$ taking values in the set $A$ is $0$, then so is the probability of $g$ taking values in the set $A$.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!